# Circuit RC, I need help with the equation.

Tags: laplace-transform

A circuit RC it's described by the next equation: $\frac{1}{c} \int i(dt)+Ri=V$ Where the value of resistance is $R=10 k\omega $ , the value of the capacitor is $C=2.5 \mu F$, and the voltage of the circuit is $V(t)=5V$. The switch that controls the circuit is closed in $t=0$ with $V_c=3V$. Calculate $i(t)$ of the circuit.

Now… I know how to calculate the $i(t)$ through laplace, I just don't know how to express $V$ on the equation with the values of $V(t)=5V$ and $V_c=3V$ in $t=0$.
Hope someone can help me.

Comment: kinda… using the values for R(d/dt)Q+1/cQ=V it gives me 3… not quite sure

Comment: Why do you divide by capacitance? IIRC, the voltage on the capacitor is $cq$ where $q$ is its charge.

Answer (score 1):

Let the capacitor charge be $q(t)$, then $i(t)=\frac{d}{dt}q(t)$.
The equation then writes  $$ c q(t)+R\frac{d}{dt}q(t)=V$$with initial data $q(0) = 3V/c$.
In other words, we need to solve the Cauchy problem
$$\begin{cases}
\dot q = -\frac cRq+\frac VR,\\
q(0)=3V/c.
\end{cases}$$
The solution is $q(t) = \frac Vc\left(2\exp(-\frac cR t) +1\right) $, $i(t) = -2\frac VR  \exp(-\frac cR t) $.

If it's unclear how to find the solution to this Cauchy problem, ask in comments.